# What semantic notions underlie 'paene' to the PIE root 'pē(i)-' (to hurt, scold, shame)?

Tags: etymology, proto-indo-european

Reading [the etymology of fiend](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=fiend) propelled me to read Univ. Texas's page on the PIE etymon     [pē(i)-, pī-      'to hurt, scold, shame'](http://www.utexas.edu/cola/centers/lrc/ielex/X/P1460.html), whose Semantic Fields are stated as:

> to Harm, Injure, Damage; Shame (n).

Under this PIE etymon, I saw the Latin adverb *paene* listed; but per  [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/paene), it does not connote or denote any negativity or injure or shame. So why was *paene* assigned to this PIE etymon?

Comment: This *does* seem a strange one. I hope somebody knows and can answer, 'cause now I'm curious.

Comment: A possible clue is English *hardly*, which shows a semantic shift from "with difficulty" to "almost". "With difficulty" and "with pain" aren't far apart.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is "paeniteo" considered more correct than "poeniteo"?](http://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/714/why-is-paeniteo-considered-more-correct-than-poeniteo)

Comment: The etymology of paene is unknown and contested. de Vaan summarizes the suggestions on record (including the derivation from  *piH-) and shows that they are all untenable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because this etymology means that *paene* would be related to *paenitet* (as, indeed, the *Oxford Latin Dictionary* indicates it is), I should think that the connection is something along these lines:

If one thing is 'almost' another thing, it falls short of that thing in some essential quality, the full possession of which would make it wholly that thing; therefore, it's 'damaged' or 'causes dissatisfaction' (one of the definitions of paenitet in *OLD*) *vis-à-vis* that thing.

Comment: Nice explanation! Welcome to the site!