# Why is "paeniteo" considered more correct than "poeniteo"?

Tags: classical-latin, vocabulary, spelling

Through [answers to another question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/711/12), I came across [Lewis & Short's definition of *paeniteo*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dpaeniteo), which begins:

> paenĭtĕo (less correctly poen- )

L&S say that it comes from the Greek *ποινή*, which to me would suggest that *poen-* would be preferred.  So what is the basis for judging *paen-* more correct than *poen-*?

Comment: I wondered the exact same thing when reading the answer. The dictionary entry relates it to *poena* and [the entry for *poena*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dpoena) mentions the word *poenitet*, not *paenitet*. Confusing...

Comment: It's funny how pronunciation affects perception: I generally use Ecclesiastical pronunciation, in which both *oe* and *ae* are more or less *e*, so the difference didn't jump out to me as it did to others.

Answer (score 5):

My guess is that the similarity between *poena* and *paenitere* led to a misunderstanding by L&S. De Vaan, for example, doesn't mention *poena* in his entry on *paenitere*:

> **paene** 'almost, practicaly' [adv.] (Pl.+)
>
> Derivatives: *paenitere* (p.. *-ui*) 'to cause dissatisfaction, cause to regret' (Pl.+) ...
>
> The basic meaning of the stem **paen-* seems to be 'missing, lacking'. IEW connects *paene* with the Skt. *piyati* scorns', which would fit if we posit *ph<sub>2</sub>-u-; but the root is reconstructed as *ph<sub>1</sub>-i- in LIV, which does not explain Latin *-ae*. Also, the semantics do not match well. Nero (2007: 78f.) takes up a suggestion by Vine and proposes **p(e)-ai-ni-* 'not entirely' < *'from whom has been taken away' or *'who takes away', from a preverb **pe* 'away' and a verb **h<sub>1</sub>ai* 'to give, take'. A PIE phoneme sequence *h<sub>1</sub>ai- is in my view not possible, however, and the existence of a PIE preverb *pe is uncertain.

*Paenitere* from *paene* seems more likely than from *poena*, and there is no way that *paene* and *poena* are related.

Comment: So you're suggesting that *pœnitere* is a misspelling?

Comment: @JoelDerfner Yes, which was very common in Medieval Latin.